# What is this tall plant with narrow leaves and white flowers?

Tags: identification, vegetables

[image]

What type of plant is this? It's tall with white flowers and narrow leaves. It is a variety of vegetable .

Comment: With [tag:identification] questions, it's useful to describe where in the world you found the plant, and the conditions where you found it (sun, shade, rocky hillside, forested riverbank, and so on). If you have more information about the plant, please update your question to add it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

They look like broad bean plants to me (Vicia faba)

Comment: Definitely would agree, they look exactly like my broad beans!

Answer (score 0):

My first impression is MULLEIN.  Check out this file of pictures.  Truly a weed but has medicinal value.  Not sure which one but you might be able to recognise what you've got.

[mullein pictures](https://www.google.com/search?q=mullein%20leaf&rlz=1C1QJDB_en&espv=2&biw=1067&bih=533&tbm=isch&imgil=S0vOdVaasNBidM%253A%253B9lemdLHGkPZwEM%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fcommons.wikimedia.org%25252Fwiki%25252FFile%25253AVerbascum_thapsus_mullein_leaf_rose_dewy.jpg&source=iu&pf=m&fir=S0vOdVaasNBidM%253A%252C9lemdLHGkPZwEM%252C_&usg=__y7t2DqkyD4dV-4iL4aI0ue4RBgw%3D&ved=0ahUKEwj01PfikvjLAhUS0GMKHe2YBOwQyjcIqQE&ei=gwYEV7SHBpKgjwPtsZLgDg#imgrc=S0vOdVaasNBidM%3A)

Comment: Mullein has no compound leaves and is more or less hairy. Note the white slowers with the dark spot on the right: @Rosie's right about fava.

Comment: cool!  Thanks Stephie for letting me know...fava makes sense, good job rosie!